# How to install epson L360 scanner

Tags: server, application-development

Problem with the installation of epson l360 image scanner, I down loaded the scanner driver but failed to instal, please help what should I do?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Details of "failed to install" please.

Comment: I have downloaded the scanner Epson l360 in version 20.04, i tried to install it but it shows that  status :Error:Dependency is not satisfiable:(^=3.14.0),image Scan be oct english plug in

Answer (score 0):

If you have dependency problems, try:

```
$ sudo apt -f install
```

You may download the **Epson Scan 2** for Linux here:

https://support.epson.net/linux/en/epsonscan2.php

For 64-bit Ubuntu this is the direct download as of 2022:

https://download2.ebz.epson.net/epsonscan2/common/deb/x64/epsonscan2-bundle-6.7.0.0.x86_64.deb.tar.gz

It is a tarfile and you will need to extract it. There is an `install.sh` file that you can run, e.g.

```
$ sh install.sh
```

or

```
$ ./install.sh
```

Or what I did is just to

```
$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

for the two `deb` files in the decompressed folders.